# Semantic ui dropdown with multiple selections not clearing text after selecting an option

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui

I have recently started working on the html and css and I was stuck in this situation where I have used semantic ui dropdown with multiple selections feature and not working as expected. (Reference: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#multiple-selection)

I have exactly used the same way as it was given in the example. But I don't know what have I missed while implementing it. I am getting the following error

[image]

Here is my html code for this dropdown

```
<select id="view_options_dd" multiple="multiple" class="ui fluid search dropdown view_ns_dropdown" data-ng-model="selected_options">
    <option data-ng-repeat="item in all_options.name">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

And corresponding javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('select.dropdown').dropdown({ fullTextSearch: true ,sortSelect:true} ,'set selected', ['meteor', 'ember']);
        });
```

Even after selecting the 'test' option, I am still getting the text in the dropdown box. Any idea how to fix this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you create a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [bin](https://jsbin.com/?html,js,output) or [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/) for this?

Comment: I have created the plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/st5aISR8wl2Vsd9Y1syO?p=preview But surprisingly, here I am not getting that problem. Then why is it coming in my project??

I have added two more screenshots from my webpage where the issue still exists. Any leads, what am I missing?

Comment: Any errors in the `console`? are you using the same version in your project and the plunkr?

Comment: Gotcha!! My local css files are not updated. Now it is working fine after updating them

Answer (score 0):

i think that is happening cuz you don't have value="" field in option. So semantic thinks that first option is a placeholder

Just put:

```
<select id="view_options_dd" multiple="multiple" class="ui fluid search dropdown view_ns_dropdown" data-ng-model="selected_options">
    <option data-ng-repeat="item in all_options.name" value='{{item}}'>{{item}}</option>
</select>
```